# What is a simple PHP File download script?

Tags: php, web, ftp

I only just bought a web domain yesterday(cryptum.net) and I intend to upload some files to it. My problem is I don't have a good PHP5 download script. I just want a simple script that will save the file to the users download folder. The files are located on the websites ftp server. Here is what I have so far-

```
<?php
$conn = ftp_connect("ftp://username@cryptum.net") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"username","password");

//download script goes here

ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another very elegant solution which uses the powerful stream features of PHP:

```
<?php
$ftp_server  = 'ftp://username:password@cryptum.net/';
$remote_file = 'user/directory/file';
$local_file  = '/path/to/the/local/file';

file_put_contents($local_file, file_get_contents($ftp_server.$destination_file));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//...
//download script goes here
ftp_get ($conn, '/destination/on/my/hardDrive', '/file/to/download'); 
//...
?>
```

and you could use php-curl instead...